# AWS CodePipeline ApplicationStop lifecycle event failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

Is it possible to configure AWS CodePipeline to not fail the deployment if ApplicationStop script fails? I know I can tick the box when I manually create a deployment via CodeDeploy, however, I can't see any way to do this for deployments created automatically by deploying code via CodePipeline.

Cheers
Kris

Comment: Can you share your application stop script

Comment: ps -ef | grep artifact-name.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill

Comment: it works if the process is already running, but fails if it is a new instance. Is it worth adding some condition to only run the stop script when process with artifact-name.jar is already running? Maybe change script to something else that automatically stops the process?

Comment: maybe it is worth creating a new pipeline for the new instances being added which doesn't have an ApplicationStop script in the build phase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that CodeDeploy automatically deploys the newest code to the auto-scaled instances if connected to the auto-scaling group. No need to run the full deploy with ApplicationStop, just need to add ApplicationStart script to launch configuration user data.

Comment: I too am having issues where my blue/green deployment fired from codepipline is sometimes failing on applicationstop and need a way to enable that setting from codepipeline. Can you explain what you did to get around this please?

Comment: Hi @Jason, what I did was I added an ApplicationStart script in the instance launch configuration user data. This means that every new instance gets the newest code version via CodeDeploy agent and just runs the ApplicationStart without ApplicationStop.

Comment: Therefore ApplicationStop script is only triggered when new code is deployed to instances that are already running instead of new instances on which ApplicationStop would fail.

Comment: ah ok that is what I already have in place but for some reason its still failing on applicationStop - thanks for coming back to my question